# ElasticSearch query doesn't return good results

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have data structure:

```
{
    first_name: Ann,
    last_name: Smith
}
```

And I want to search records use query:

1. AND: first_name = Ann AND last_name = Smith
2. OR: first_name = Ann OR last_name = Smith
3. LIKE:  first_name = *n* AND last_name = *mi*
4. get total count records witch accept query

I try to use Java-code for searching:

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
TransportClient transportClient = new TransportClient(settings);
transportClient = transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));

Client client = transportClient;

SearchRequestBuilder srb1 = client.prepareSearch().setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("firstName", firstName));
SearchRequestBuilder srb2 = client.prepareSearch().setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("lastName", lastName));

MultiSearchResponse query = client.prepareMultiSearch()
            .add(srb1)
            .add(srb2)
            .execute().actionGet();

for (MultiSearchResponse.Item item : query.getResponses()) {
        SearchResponse response = item.getResponse();
        System.out.println(response);
}
transportClient.close();
client.close();
```

But I haven't a good result. And ElasticSearch Java API documentations are very scanty.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
SearchRequestBuilder srb1 = client.prepareSearch().setQuery(QueryBuilders
                .boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("first_name", "Ann"))
                .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("last_name", "Smith")));
```

Above query will give you results for `first_name = Ann AND last_name = Smith`

```
SearchRequestBuilder srb2 = client.prepareSearch().setQuery(QueryBuilders
                .boolQuery()
                .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("first_name", "Ann"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("last_name", "Smith")));
```

Above query will give you results for `first_name = Ann OR last_name = Smith`

```
SearchRequestBuilder srb3 = client.prepareSearch().setQuery(QueryBuilders
                .boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("first_name", "n*"))
                .must(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("last_name", "mi*")));
```

Above query will give you results for `first_name starting with n AND last_name starting with mi

BTW `prepareMultiSearch` is used only to send multiple search requests to ES using single request (less communication overhead).

Please take a look there: http://search-lucene.com/. You can find tons of useful information about Elasticsearch, Lucene, Solr and related projects.